# administrative_area_level_2 missing when search using address, but not when using latlng

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Why is it that I do not get the administrative_area_level_2 ("Viborg") returned when searching for "Karup" (not using the latlng query)?

When searching for an address (1. example above), is there a way to make it so the geocoder does not skip e.g. the administrative_area_level_2 in the resultset?

Examples:

Searching for "Karup" in Denmark using this:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:DK&address=Karup&language=da

return the following interesting information (see RESULTS-1 below for full resultset)... NOTE THAT "administrative_area_level_2 ("Viborg") is missing here:

```
"long_name" : "Karup",
"short_name" : "Karup",
"types" : [ "locality", "political" ]

"long_name" : "Danmark",
"short_name" : "DK",
"types" : [ "country", "political" ]

"location" : {"lat" : 56.307765, "lng" : 9.1676629 }
```

THEN, if I use the latlng values from location in my first result like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=56.307765,9.1676629&language=da
```

(see RESULTS-2 below  for full resultset), then I get these interesting parts (among others):

```
"long_name" : "Karup",
"short_name" : "Karup",
"types" : [ "locality", "political" ]

"long_name" : "Viborg",
"short_name" : "Viborg",
"types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]

"long_name" : "Danmark",
"short_name" : "DK",
"types" : [ "country", "political" ]
```

RESULTS-1:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Karup",
               "short_name" : "Karup",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Danmark",
               "short_name" : "DK",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "7470",
               "short_name" : "7470",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "7470 Karup, Danmark",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 56.41066989999999,
                  "lng" : 9.320741199999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 56.2160131,
                  "lng" : 9.022918599999999
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 56.307765,
               "lng" : 9.1676629
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 56.41066989999999,
                  "lng" : 9.320741199999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 56.2160131,
                  "lng" : 9.022918599999999
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ7wqM9R3CS0YRNUycN6M8YeY",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

RESULTS-2 (from latlng and only first item in address_components array):

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "5A",
               "short_name" : "5A",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Genvej",
               "short_name" : "Genvej",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Karup J",
               "short_name" : "Karup J",
               "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Karup",
               "short_name" : "Karup",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Viborg",
               "short_name" : "Viborg",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Danmark",
               "short_name" : "DK",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "7470",
               "short_name" : "7470",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Genvej 5A, 7470 Karup J, Danmark",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 56.30788,
               "lng" : 9.167926999999999
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 56.30922898029149,
                  "lng" : 9.1692759802915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 56.3065310197085,
                  "lng" : 9.166578019708496
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJFRksv_7BS0YRxyN0NOqp11I",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      },
```

Comment: i think you can get latlong using address and then you can pass that lat long.....same thing i also used in my page

Comment: Thank you very much Jaykumar Gondaliya. That works. But it would have been nice to not have to do two requests against the geocoder.